# Split DNS to access server from internal and external network with same subdomain

Tags: dns, subdomain, nat

I want to access my servers from the external as well as the internal network by accessing it with the same subdomain. Therefore, I hosted a private DNS server in my network to resolve the subdomain with the internal IP when a host from the internal network tries to resolve the subdomain. For the access of external networks I added CNAME entries to resolve the subdomain with the static public IP that I have. My configuration looks like this:

**Public DNS Server (External)**

- A - mydomain.com - External IP
- CNAME - www.mydomain.com - mydomain.com (301 Redirect)
- CNAME - server1.mydomain.com - mydomain.com (301 Redirect)
- CNAME - server2.mydomain.com - mydomain.com (301 Redirect)

**Private DNS Server (Internal)**

- A - server1.mydomain.com - Internal IP of server 1
- A - server2.mydomain.com - Internal IP of server 2

My question now is whether this is a good setup or not and whether this will have a bad effect for my website in the search engines. I need this because my rooter doesn't support NAT loopback and I need a workaround to access the servers internal and external with the same subdomain.

Comment: This seems like a question better suited to ServerFault than StackOverflow. (Or maybe Webmasters if you want an SEO perspective). It does seem opinion based though.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general, you have 2 servers in internal, right? 
if you have more than 1 ip public for your server,
just set:

```
A - server1.mydomain.com - IP Public 1
A - server2.mydomain.com - IP Public 2
```

on your router set dest NAT

from IP public 1 to  Internal IP of server 1
from IP public 2 to  Internal IP of server 2

and for internal, you just add server DNS local
your concept is good :

```
A - server1.mydomain.com - Internal IP of server 1
A - server2.mydomain.com - Internal IP of server 2
```

For client access DNS, in DHCP you set to your internal DNS, in your internal DNS just you can forward to public DNS

You can use BIND for DNS Server in Linux environment, or in windows server just add DNS server and configure.

Comment: The problem is that I only have one public IP for my router, so I use different ports to access the servers.

Comment: If you use 301 redirect, in SEO will not make your rank decreases  [link] (https://d1avok0lzls2w.cloudfront.net/uploads/blog/579f8a13b1ab83.23472435.jpg)